# Prefab Move on the Host Side but Not On the Client (Unity Netcode)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer

Can anyone help please? I have spent over two days trying different approaches, but nothing works.

Here is link of unity answer community to solve my problem and store it for anyone face it in the future:
https://discussions.unity.com/t/prefab-move-on-the-host-side-but-not-on-the-client-unity-netcode/321395

- Unity version: 2023.2.3
- F1netcode version: 1.7.1

Prefab on the Scriptable Object has a Network object, network transfom and rigidbody.

The client can spawn the prefab but the prefab can’t move.but on the host he can spawn the prefab and the prefab can moveand the movement btw it synced.

I have another script responsible of interacting with object and grabbing them and it’s working fine on both sides.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using Unity.Netcode;
public class ShootingSystem : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform startPointTransform;
    [SerializeField] private List<Weapon_SO> weapon_SOs = new List<Weapon_SO>();
    [SerializeField] private float rangeModefier = 10;
    
    private int weaponIndex = 0;
    [Range(0f,1f)]
    private float holdTime = 0;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;
        if (InputsData.IsShootingStarted())
        {
            //start counting the holding time
            if (holdTime <= 1)
                holdTime += Time.deltaTime;

        }else if (InputsData.IsShootingReleased())
        {
            //shoot
            SpawnAndMovePrefabOnServerRpc(startPointTransform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            holdTime = 0;
        }
    }
    [ServerRpc]
    private void SpawnAndMovePrefabOnServerRpc(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot)
    {
        GameObject InstantiatedObject = Instantiate(weapon_SOs[weaponIndex].projectilePrefab, pos, rot);
        NetworkObject networkObject = InstantiatedObject.GetComponent<NetworkObject>();
        networkObject?.Spawn();

        Move(networkObject.NetworkObjectId);
        Destroy(InstantiatedObject, 3f);
    }
    void Move(ulong id)
    {

        Transform cameraPosition = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().transform;
        Vector3 moveDirection = (cameraPosition.up * weapon_SOs[weaponIndex].upModefier + cameraPosition.forward * weapon_SOs[weaponIndex].forwadModefier)
            * weapon_SOs[weaponIndex].range * rangeModefier * holdTime;

        GetNetworkObject(id)?.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(moveDirection);
    }
}
[![[![[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLRPV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLRPV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36bTU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36bTU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F4Ci.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F4Ci.png)
```

I tried to write the movement of the prefab on the prefab it self OnNetworkSpawn() method but the same thing happened .